# Need a .bat file that pulls file name, path and modified date

Tags: csv, batch-file

I have a .bat file that I place in the root of a directory.  It goes through the entire directory and pulls the file name and file path and writes it to a .csv file.  I need to add the date modified.  Can anyone help me?

```
@echo off
echo Creating CSV from Folder Contents, please wait....
(for /r %%F in (*) do @echo "%%~nxF","%%~dpF") >FileList.csv
echo CSV has been created
pause
```

Comment: I bet if you read the help file for the `FOR` command you would see it plain as day.  You apparently already know what four of the command modifiers do.  There is a whole list of them at the bottom of the help file. Open up a cmd prompt and type: `FOR /?`

Comment: You can also find a lot of good information on [`FOR`](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) and other batch commands at [SS64's CMD.EXE reference](https://ss64.com/nt/).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [parameter extensions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html), which is what you're already using with `%%~nxF` and `%%~dpF`. The `~nx` and `~dp` pieces of text are part of parameter extensions which is a whole collection of special shortcut operations you can use with parameters.

To get Date Modified, use `~t`, so your full parameter reference will look like `%%~tF`, and your script like this...

```
@echo off
echo Creating CSV from Folder Contents, please wait....
(for /r %%F in (*) do @echo "%%~nxF","%%~dpF", %%~tF) >FileList.csv
echo CSV has been created
pause
```